# Casting null or falsy values to undefined

Tags: javascript

I would like to turn any falsy value to undefined so that a particular property won't be added to the resulting JSON object.

```
const response = {
  myValue: 'someString',
  errorMessage: error && 'An unexpected error occurred'
};
```

Here, I would like the `errorMessage` property to resolve to `undefined` when the `error` object is `null`. Unfortunately, when there's no error, the `errorMessage` property becomes `null` instead of `undefined`, resulting in it being included in the final object. Is there syntax available to prevent this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can append `|| undefined` to the end of the statement and it should work fine.

```js
const error = null
const response = {
  myValue: 'someString',
  errorMessage: error && 'An unexpected error occurred' || undefined
};
console.log(JSON.stringify(response))
```

Answer (score 1):

use a ternary

```js
const error = false;

const response = {
  myValue: 'someString',
  errorMessage: error ? 'An unexpected error occurred' : undefined
};

const json = JSON.stringify(response);

console.log(json)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const response = {
      myValue: 'someString',
      errorMessage: error?error:undefined
    };
```